# WCF service issues with external IP

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I'm facing very strange problem with my WCF application.
I have an IIS hosted WCF service.
Here is the web.config of the service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="600" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="SyncWcfServices.MainServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="ExtendedMaxSize" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"></binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service name="SyncWcfServices.MainService" behaviorConfiguration="SyncWcfServices.MainServiceBehavior">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ExtendedMaxSize" contract="SyncWcfServices.IMainService">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/SyncWcfServices/MainService/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

It's configured as a web-site running under IIS using special port number.
Client for that service is a WPF application. The part of code responsible for service interaction:

```
public BMS_SYNC_DOC[] GetDocuments(POSAuthorizationModel data)
{
    using (var service = this.GetSyncService())
    {
        return service.GetDocuments(data);
    }
}

private MainServiceClient GetSyncService()
{
    var service = new MainServiceClient();
    service.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(Configuration.SyncServiceUrl);

    return service;
}
```

Everything works fine while using the client within the same network (e.g. `Configuration.SyncServiceUrl = "192.168.0.111:3333/SyncService.svc"`)
But when I'm trying to run it from the external network it fails.
Somewhat like

```
Configuration.SyncServiceUrl = "25.35.45.55:3333/SyncService.svc".
```

25.35.45.55 is an external IP address of the company. I have mapped the port to my IIS server on the Firewall and when I open url above from the web-browser I can see the service description.

And here is the stack trace of the error:

```
The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.Close()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
   at SyncCore.Helpers.ServiceHelper.GetDocuments(POSAuthorizationModel data)
   at SyncClient.MainWindow.<>c__DisplayClass4.<ReloadData>b__3()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SyncClient.MainWindow.<ReloadData>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at SyncClient.MainWindow.<Reload>d__0.MoveNext()
```

I think there are some configurtion issues either on IIS or in my service config files. But I cannot find proper solution.

Any ideas?


**Edit:**
I've solved that.
Changed security mode and transport clientCredentialType to None in Web.config.

Comment: That exception is not the first exception but a follow-up exception. Find the real exception that happened when you made the call. WCF clients are a bit nasty to dispose. Google that, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Posting an MOD IP address on stackoverflow Legendary....